# Facebook PHP API Error #100: Parameter 'input token' required

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-login

I have a Facebook app using the Login with Facebook function which was working earlier and isn't now.

I get the login URL with the following code:

```
$fb_helper = $login_providers['fb']->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$fb_login_url = $fb_helper->getLoginUrl(/* my callback URL */, array('email'));
```

At the callback URL, I then use $fb_helper->getAccessToken which returns the following exception.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException' with message '(#100) The parameter input_token is required' in /home/kgur5734/public_html/left/system/libraries/Facebook/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php:100 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/kgur5734/public_html/left/system/libraries/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php(210): Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException::create(Object(Facebook\FacebookResponse)) 
#1 /home/kgur5734/public_html/left/system/libraries/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php(255): Facebook\FacebookResponse->makeException() 
#2 /home/kgur5734/public_html/left/system/libraries/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php(82): Facebook\FacebookResponse->decodeBody() 
#3 /home/kgur5734/public_html/left/system/libraries/Facebook/FacebookClient.php(225): Facebook\FacebookResponse->__construct(Object(Facebook\FacebookRequest), '{"error":{"mess...', 400, Array) 
#4 /home/kgur5734/public_html/left/system/libraries/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php(118): Facebook\FacebookClient->sendRequest(Object(F in /home/kgur5734/public_html/left/system/libraries/Facebook/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php on line 100
```

Any ideas, Stack Overflow?